# How to search only indexed files in Windows 8's File Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, search

Windows 8's File Explorer searches every file in the computer, how do I change it to search only files in Indexed Locations? I don't want to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> since I want the search result window to remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I found: you can go to a folder and search only that folder. So you can do this:

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Right-click **Libraries** on the left.
3. Click **New -> Library**. Give it a name, eg: **IndexedFiles**.
4. Now go to one of your indexed folder and right-click it, then click 
   **Include in Library -> IndexedFiles**.
5. Continue step 3 for all your indexed folders.
6. Now you can search only indexed files, just click **IndexedFiles** on the left, then type something in the search box at top right.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to disable searching non-indexed locations in File Explorer. File Explorer will always search both indexed and non-indexed locations. You just get faster results when looking at Indexed locations.